# Persist new parent entity only if linked entity already exist in the database with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

I have an entity Video that needs to be written to a database with Java/Hibernate. Each video can have one or more tags. Currently, there are only certain tags that can be used (predefined and managed in another place).

Videos can be edited and created via REST API.

Now, I want to persist a new Video with tags into the database, but there should be no persist if one or more tags do not already exist in the database.

My first idea would be to query each tag before the persist if it exists in the database and fail with the first match.

But I think there are many unnecessary queries and I would like to know if there is something easier I can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the corresponding tags before saving record to the database in your service method as shown below (you might update it to check multiple tags):

```
public void create(FileRequest request) {
    if (tagRepository.existsByNameIgnoreCase(request.getTagName())) {        
        throw new ElementAlreadyExistsException("File with same tag already exists");
    }
    // save file 
}
```